# Positioning blocks dynamically

Tags: beamer, transition

Is there a transition that helps me to adjust the placement of blocks when I add more information in subsequent slides?

I would like the first block to appear centered in the middle, then on the next slide the first box moves up to make space for the second block etc. The default is that the first box is positioned at the top straightaway.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Abstract}
\begin{exampleblock}<1->{In this presentation ...}
... here is some text. 
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{exampleblock}<2->{We will also cover ... }
 ... here is some more text. 
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The second exampleblock comes in on the second slide, prior to that I would tile the first example block to be centered in the middle of the page.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Most certainly! Can you provide the working foundation for this via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: What do you use for the transition? `\pause` or `\only<>{}` or something else?

Comment: @Werner apologies for the omission! I've added it now, thanks for your comment!

Comment: @samcarter I use \pause sometimes, but also the option that I've used above for the minimal working example. I haven't come across the \only<>{} option, thanks for mentioning this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `\only<>{}` gives your desired result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Abstract}
\only<1->{
    \begin{exampleblock}{In this presentation ...}
    ... here is some text. 
    \end{exampleblock}
}

\only<2->{
    \begin{exampleblock}{We will also cover ... }
     ... here is some more text. 
    \end{exampleblock}
}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```